# Beta function as result of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

I have been reading this [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714132/use-of-a-laplace-transform-to-solve-abels-integral-equation). In part of the solution there is an integral which leads to beta function but I don't know how. Here it is

\begin{align}
\int_0^t\frac{f(\tau)}{(t-\tau)^{1-\alpha }}d\tau&=\int_0^t \frac{1}{(t-\tau)^{1-\alpha }}\left(\int_0^\tau\frac{\phi(x)}{(\tau-x)^\alpha }dx \right)d\tau\\
&=\int_0^t\phi(x)\left(\int_x^t \frac{1}{(t-\tau)^{1-\alpha }(\tau-x)^\alpha }  \right)dx\\
&=B(\alpha ,1-\alpha )\int_0^t \phi(x)dx.
\end{align}
Why is second integral equal to the third one and how is it equal to beta function?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx=\text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$ if $\alpha,\beta>0$. For that little problem, let $u=\tau-x$, so that $du=d\tau$:

$$\begin{split}\int_x^t \frac{1}{(t-\tau)^{1-\alpha}(\tau-x)^\alpha}d\tau
&=\int_0^{t-x}\frac 1{(t-u-x)^{1-\alpha}u^\alpha}du\end{split}$$

Assume $t-x=1$, then

$$\begin{split}\int_0^{1}\frac 1{(1-u)^{1-\alpha}u^\alpha}du&=\int_0^1 u^{-\alpha+1-1}(1-u)^{\alpha-1}du\\
&=\text{Beta}(1-\alpha, \alpha)\end{split}$$

Comment: but why is second integral equal to third one?!

Comment: @FreeMind It is simply changing the order of integration. The only non-trivial part is figuring out how it changes the limits of integrations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)

Comment: @FreeMind The area of integration, in a 2D plane, is a triangle. If you draw out the triangle and switch the order of integration, we'd find those limits.